# mongodb and pentaho CDE dashboard

Tags: mongodb, pentaho, pentaho-cde

I want to create CDE dashboard which contains charts, tables and many more functionality and I want to use mongodb as database creating dashboard. But, when I go through pentaho CE 5.0 CDE dashboard there was no any options to connect to mongodb like sql queries or sql over JNDI. Can any one knows how to make CDE dashboard using MongoDB data source?

Answer (score 1):

Use a Kettle transformation to get data from Mongo and a CDA over Kettle to get that data into the dashboard.